# Is there a way to use PHP PDO with SplFixedArray when dataset is known?

Tags: php, pdo

I would like to use https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php together with a query that returns a dataset of defined length.

Does PDO support fetching into http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php object or do I need to iterate the result set?

Comment: Why do you need SplFixedArray, what's wrong with "iterating the resultset" and why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: I would like to pass `SplFixedArray` to another class, while the default PHP array consumes too much memory. This isn't a case of TIAS – I don't know whether there is a way of doing this other than iterating the buffered statement first.

Answer (score 0):

If standard array consumes too much memory, then pass a PDO statement instead, and iterate over it, using `PDOStatement::fetch()`. 
It will consume no memory at all (especially if you set `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` to `false`)

Comment: That's what I was doing. In my case this doesn't work because the end class is expecting an array, which has to be pre-processed before it is passed.

Comment: Finally, knowing a way to create `SplFixedArray` from PDO result set is generally a nice trick to have up your sleeve.